# How to load the JSON file too the PSQL database

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a JSON file. Now I need to load the JSON data to my PSQL database.

So far I tried this one

```
import psycopg2
import json
with open('new.json') as f:
    data = f.read()
    dd = json.loads(data)
    conn = psycopg2.connect(database="newdb", user = "postgres",  password = "postgres",host = "127.0.0.1", port = "5432")

    print "Opened database successfully"

    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute(''' CREATE TABLE jsontable(SUM INT NOT NULL,
                                      APP  CHAR[30] NOT NULL,
                                      ID INT NOT NULL,
                                      DOMAINNAME TEXT NOT NULL,
                                      DOMAINID INT NOT NULL);''')
    print "Table Created successfully"


    cur.execute('''INSERT INTO jsontable(data)
                   VALUES(%s)
                ''',
                     (data, str(dd['sum'],str(dd['app'],str(dd['id'],str(dd['Domain_name'],str(dd['Domain_Id'])))

print ("Data Entered successfully")
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Please provide some examples, how to pass the JSON file data to the database

Comment: The table you created is different from the one you're inserting the values into

Comment: Assume I need to insert my JSON file data into the same table.                              my new.json file --------------->                                                                                   [{
 "sum": 2102.0,
 "app": "java",
 "appId": "1234",
 "Domain_name": "medicine",
 "Domain_Id": "20000123"
}, {
 "sum": 1800.0,
 "app": "python",
 "appId": "37345",
 "Domain_name": "engineering",
 "Domain_Id": "823445"
}]

Answer (score 0):

Personally I like [asyncpg](https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/usage.html#) as it's fully async especially if you're using Python 3.x and essentially all you need to do is put await in front of the sync commands.

```
import asyncpg
import json
with open('new.json') as f:
    data = f.read()
    dd = json.loads(data)
    conn = await asyncpg.connect(database="newdb", user = "postgres",  password = "postgres",host = "127.0.0.1", port = "5432")    
    print "Opened database successfully"
    await con.execute(''' CREATE TABLE jsontable(SUM INT NOT NULL,
                                      APP  CHAR[30] NOT NULL,
                                      ID INT NOT NULL,
                                      DOMAINNAME TEXT NOT NULL,
                                      DOMAINID INT NOT NULL);''')
    print "Table Created successfully"


    await con.execute('''INSERT INTO jsontable(SUM, APP, ID, DOMAINNAME, DOMAINID)
                   VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)
                ''',(str(dd['sum'],str(dd['app'],str(dd['id'],str(dd['Domain_name'],str(dd['Domain_Id'])))

print ("Data Entered successfully")
await conn.commit()
await conn.close()
```

Comment: I am using python 2.7.15 version

Comment: Why did you include 3.X in your question then?

Comment: Still, you can use the PGSQL statements I have in there

Comment: cur.execute('''INSERT INTO jsontable(SUM,APP,ID,DOMAINNAME,DOMAINID) VALUES($1,$2,$3,$4,$5)''', (str(dd["sum"]),str(dd["app"]),str(dd["id"]),str(dd["Domain_name"]),str(dd["Domain_Id"])))
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str